# Get ciphering algorithm via AT Commands

Tags: cryptography, gsm, modem, at-command

I'm trying to get what kind of ciphering algorithm is used by a phone at the current moment via AT Commands. Usually it's A5/1 or A5/0. Has anyone faced a similar situation? Do you know any other way to get the algorithm?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is A5/0? What has this to do with programming?

Comment: A5/0 is another algorithm that has no encryption at all. I am writing a program that runs on a mobile device and collects what encryption algorithm the user uses at a specific time. This is done by Nokia's netmonitor in test 12 (ntnu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:355716/FULLTEXT01 - page 85). I'm looking to get that via an AT Command (or any other possible way). Thanks for your reply @owlstead :)

Comment: Any specific phone or modem you're using? Different devices will have different AT commands (if they support it at all.)

Comment: I have an Iphone and I am currently sending commands via minicom and ssh. But any device that could do it I'd be willing to work with it :)

Comment: For anyone looking for this, if your device has a Qualcomm modem (we used a samsung phone) you can get the algorithms with a tool called QXDM. Still haven't found a way to get it via AT Commands.